# Initializing meta-data on drbd resource wipes existing data?

Tags: heartbeat, drbd

I upgraded centos 6.4 to 6.10 on 1 node and after that installed drbd package(listed below) stopped working

drbd-km-2.6.32_358.11.1.el6.x86_64-8.4.3-2.el6.x86_64
drbd-km-2.6.32_358.6.2.el6.x86_64-8.4.3-2.el6.x86_64
drbd-utils-8.4.3-2.el6.x86_64

I wasn't able to find any update for this so I removed it and installed below drbd packages

kmod-drbd83-8.3.16-3.el6.elrepo.x86_64
drbd83-utils-8.3.16-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64

after that it is giving me below error on drbd service start

```
[root@node1 etc]# /etc/init.d/drbd start
Starting DRBD resources: [
data
no suitable meta data found :(
Command '/sbin/drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/local/data internal check-resize' terminated with exit code 255
drbdadm check-resize data: exited with code 255
d(data) 0: Failure: (119) No valid meta-data signature found.

        ==> Use 'drbdadm create-md res' to initialize meta-data area. <==


[data] cmd /sbin/drbdsetup 0 disk /dev/local/data /dev/local/data internal --set-defaults --create-device --on-io-error=detach  failed - continuing!

s(data) ].
```

ALso below is the current status of drbd service

```
drbd driver loaded OK; device status:
version: 8.3.16 (api:88/proto:86-97)
GIT-hash: a798fa7e274428a357657fb52f0ecf40192c1985 build by phil@Build64R6, 2014-11-24 14:51:37
m:res   cs         ro                 ds                 p  mounted  fstype
0:data  Connected  Secondary/Primary  Diskless/UpToDate  C
```

If I run drbdadm create-md res to initialize meta-data, will it wipe disk on that node and will it affect node2 data?

Or it will wipe only node1 disk and that will be synced later with node2?

tried installing below packages and start drbd service

kmod-drbd83-8.3.16-3.el6.elrepo.x86_64
drbd83-utils-8.3.16-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to go from DRBD 8.4.x -> 8.3.x. You cannot "downgrade" DRBD without recreating metadata on both nodes.

If you `drbdadm create-md res` on both nodes and accept the warning messages, your data will be kept. Only the DRBD metadata will be wiped and recreated.

It is still a good idea to take a backup of your data just in case. You can also "downgrade" one node at a time, to make sure the data looks good on the downgraded node before downgrading the peer.

Comment: Issue was that, 8.4 package was compiled with old kernel version that is why it stopped working after OS upgrade. So I re-compiled it with current OS version and then installed RPMs. After that it worked fine